# How to prevent Excel from removing zero(s) for number starting with zero(s) from java

Tags: java, csv

I'm creating CSV/XlS file using Java, I need to write a column having numbers like 005292, but even after writing the number as a string, excel sheet displays it as 5292.

```
StatefulBeanToCsv<FepAccount> writer = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<FepAndEabAccount>(
                    response.getWriter()).withSeparator('\t').withOrderedResults(false).build();

// write data to csv file
writer.write(fleetIncentiveService.downloadFepEabReport(request));
```

In "FepAccount" I've created POJO class for columns (all columns are of String type) using "@CsvBindByName".

For example:

```
public class FepAccount { 
    @CsvBindByName(column = "ITEM_NUMBER")
    protected String itemNumber;
        
        public String itemNumber() {
        return itemNumber;
    }
    public void setItemNumber(String itemNumber) {
        this.itemNumber= itemNumber;
    }

}
```

Comment: Assign the cells a custom numerical format or pad the strings with zeroes.

Comment: If you create a CSV file and open it with Excel you have no chance. Excel's automatisms will interpret this always as a number. You can manually import the data in Excel and set the field to text. Or you use a library which is able to create the Excel format directly and set the field type to text programmatically.

Comment: First are your item numbers padded with zeros? You don't show that you're padding them. Second, what about including `"`s in the string, that way excel will treat them as strings. Maybe you can make a complete compilable example?

Comment: What if I you write the number surrounded by double quotes. or maybe a startng sngle quote?

Comment: Consider using Apache POI to directly create the Excel sheet, instead of using CSV. CSV has no concept of string types, number types, etc. That is entirely up to the thing loading the CSV files, and Excel likely reads it as "this has only digits, so I'll treat it as a number".

Answer (score 0):

To open the csv correctly you have to:

1. Open an empty excel
2. Click on Data -> From text/CSV
   [image]
3. Select your CSV file
4. On the preview dialog box, on the Data Type Detection select "**Do not detect data types**" option.
   [image]
5. Click Load
6. Delete extra sheets (CSV file can contain only one sheet)
   [image]
7. Go to File -> Export -> Change File Type -> Select CSV -> Click on Save As
   [image]